# before_filter: is it possible to specify controller for action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I'm having the following string in my application_controller:

```
  before_filter :login_required, :only => [ :edit, :update, :show, :index ]
```

But in case with :show, I need to put {:controller => 'users', :action => 'show'} in exception. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Options:

- Use a [skip_before_filter](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000323) in the UsersController

  `skip_before_filter :login_required, :only => :show`
- Applying the before_filter individually to each controller, if your exceptional cases grow.

Comment: This works but somehow feels wrong: the authentication logic is spread all over the application.